# best way to use multiple mutex one for each structure ? (2 structures being manipulated by 4 threads for example)

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I am working for the first time on a "large" scale with threads in C and i am uncertain about how to properly use multiple mutex with each mutex protecting a structure and the structure possibly being manipulated by multiple threads

consider the following code

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct example{
    int parameter;
};

void *do_something(void *argument);

int main(){
    struct example *ex1 = (struct example *) malloc(sizeof(struct example));
    struct example *ex2 = (struct example *) malloc(sizeof(struct example));
    
    ex1->parameter = 5;
    ex2->parameter = 4;

    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_t thread3;
    pthread_t thread4;

    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL, do_something, ex1);
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL, do_something, ex1);
    pthread_create(&thread3,NULL, do_something, ex2);
    pthread_create(&thread4,NULL, do_something, ex2);

    return 0;
}

void *do_something(void *argument){
    struct example *something = (struct example *) argument;
    something->parameter = something->parameter +1; 
    return NULL;
}
```

what is the best way to assign two mutex one for ex1 and the other for ex2 in the code above? i have a couple of ideas in my mind but i'm not sure which one will work and which will make a catastrophe
for example

```c
struct parameters{
    struct example *example;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
};

struct parameters *param
pthread_create(&thread1,NULL, do_something, param);
```

or maybe even including the mutex in the very first structure so it's like

```c
struct example{
    int parameter;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
};
```

i'm not sure which is better or whether both are usuable at all, i'd love to hear some opinions, pointers or even readup recommendations before i commit into a method and it turns out to be a catastrophe

Comment: A tip: your first example has a lot of casts in it, none of which are necessary. It's a good idea to get out of the habit of putting casts in where they're not needed: a cast says to the compiler "trust me, I know this may be dangerous but I know what I'm doing", so the compiler won't warn you if you make a mistake. They're sometimes necessary, but using them too much means you will make mistakes the compiler then won't catch (plus it makes the code harder to read).

Comment: Casts for other than arithmetic purposes almost always have bad code smell.  Avoid them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the best way to assign two mutex one for ex1 and the other for ex2 in the code above?

The most natural way to associate a separate mutex with each instance of a given structure type is to make it a member of that type.  That's not always possible, but when you form the association any other way, you are susceptible to the problem of how to determine from a given structure instance which is the mutex that goes with it.

That is, if it is `struct example` for which you want mutexes then

> ```
> struct example{
>     int parameter;
>     pthread_mutex_t lock;
> };
> ```